# animal sacrifice during eid al adha for vegans and vegeterians

Tags: conversion, sacrifice, eid-ul-adha

salam alaykom brothers and sisters in islam as you may already know a lot of vegeterians and vegan cases that want to convert to islam but isnt sure that they can still be vegan or vegeterian , is it permissible for a muslim to be vegan ( against animal cruelty and sacrifice and with animal and nature peace ) and yet be a good muslim after all please give valid arguments about this matter knowing that sacrifice is only a sunnah and not their blood or their flesh that reaches Allah but attakwa ?

Comment: Salam and welcome to islam SE the Q&A site about islam. Please consider learning more about our site and model by taking our  [tour] and visiting our [help]. To your concern how can an animal sacrifice be considred as only a sunnah if it is necassry act to make the mandatory hajj valid in most of the cases?

Comment: and you can some answers also here [Giving money instead of buying an animal](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/giving-money-instead-of-buying-an-animal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Can read the comments below my answer and let us know what your intention of writing was? We are confused.

Comment: I'd like to add that i lately heard on the radio that in Italy they would like to announce a law according which vegan parents who feed their little children in vegan manner might be punished, as vegan food is not fulfilling the needs of children to a certain age!

Answer (score 1):

As a vegetarian Muslim, I found a workaround by donating to a mosque that will slaughter the same animal whether or not I donate.  This provides sufficient [diffusion of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility) for me to feel comfortable about killing an animal, while still participating in an important Muslim event.

I personally do not feel that kindness to animals is a character flaw.  I think it's reasonable to be hesitant to participate in this:

[image: graphic image of sheep being slaughtered]

(Image source: [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3248041/Muslims-world-gather-sacrifice-cattle-celebration-Eid-al-Adha-festival-families-look-on.html); link contains further graphic images)

### Qur'an

As a whole, the impression I got from reading the whole Qur'an was that (some) animals were intended to be eaten by man.  One could reasonably argue that eating meat is encouraged by the Qur'an.  For example:

> **So eat of that [meat] upon which the name of Allah has been mentioned**, if you are believers in His verses.  **And why should you not eat of that upon which the name of Allah has been mentioned** while He has explained in detail to you what He has forbidden you, excepting that to which you are compelled. And indeed do many lead [others] astray through their [own] inclinations without knowledge. Indeed, your Lord - He is most knowing of the transgressors. [Qur'an 6:118-119](https://quran.com/6:118)

Note that we also say [bismillah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala) ("in the name of God") over vegetarian food.  [Islamic Studies](http://www.islamicstudies.info/tafheem.php?sura=6&verse=112) suggests the intention is to "recognize... as lawful all that God has declared to be lawful".  [Marwan Boustany](http://www.detailedquran.com/quran_data/Halal%20and%20haram%20food%20in%20Qur%27an.htm) similarly contests this is referring to meat literally, writing "This is not the case though, as Allah has not indicated this in these verses".  [Your mileage may vary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary) as to whether or not this implies a command to eat meat or an assertion that it's okay to eat meat, or something else.

The Qur'an also has:

> And the camels and cattle We have appointed for you as among the symbols of Allah; for you therein is good. So mention the name of Allah upon them when lined up [for sacrifice]; and **when they are [lifeless] on their sides, then eat from them and feed the needy and the beggar**. Thus have We subjected them to you that you may be grateful. -- [Qur'an 22:36](http://quran.com/22:36)

It's hard to tell if this sacrifice should be interpreted as an obligation or not, but it's certainly not discouraged.

Some translations of [Qur'an 21:107](http://islamawakened.com/quran/21/107/) include kindness to animals:

> We sent thee not, but as a Mercy for all creatures.

while others do not.

> We have sent you forth as a mercy to all mankind.

I've seen claims that these ayah support vegetarianism:

> The seven heavens and the earth and whatever is in them exalt Him. And there is not a thing except that it exalts [ Allah ] by His praise, but you do not understand their [way of] exalting. Indeed, He is ever Forbearing and Forgiving. -- [Qur'an 17:44](http://quran.com/17:44)
>
> And there is no creature on [or within] the earth or bird that flies with its wings except [that they are] communities like you. We have not neglected in the Register a thing. Then unto their Lord they will be gathered. -- [Qur'an 6:38](https://quran.com/6:38)

As far as I can tell, it's just [wishful thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishful_thinking) to think they support vegetarianism.

While I'm not happy about it, I believe an honest reading of the Qur'an does not encourage being vegetarian, although it doesn't directly oppose being vegetarian.  [As such, I'm conflicted about being vegetarian.]

In a way, I feel it's analogous to being invited over to someone's house, and when they offer you something to eat, you refuse.  Well, we're in Allah's house, and he's offering meat.

### Ahadith

The Prophet Muhammad was reported to have encouraged the slaughter during Eid:

> "I attended (the day of) sacrifice with the Messenger of Allah He led the people 9in prayer, then when he finished praying he saw some sheep that had been sacrificed. He said 'Whoever slaughtered (his sacrifice) before the prayer. Let him slaughtered (his sacrifice) before the prayer, let him slaughter a sheep in its place, and **whoever has not slaughtered, let him offer a sacrifice in the name of Allah**, the Mighty and Sublime."' ([Sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/nasai/43/8); [Islam Q&A](http://islamqa.info/en/69917) assert this was during Eid ul-Adha)

The Prophet Muhammad was reported to have personally sacrificed animals:

> The Prophet sacrificed two horned rams which were white with black markings and had been castrated. ([Sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/16/8))

The Prophet Muhammad was reported to have encouraged the sacrifice of animals:

> The Companions of the Messenger of Allah said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, what are these sacrifices?’ He said: ‘The Sunnah of your father Ibrahim.’ They said: ‘What is there for us in them, O Messenger of Allah?’ He said: ‘For every hair, one merit.’ They said: ‘What about wool, O Messenger of Allah?’ He said: ‘For every hair of wool, one merit.’ ([Sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/urn/1272300))

At the same time, the Prophet Muhammad was reported to have prescribed relatively painless methods for slaughtering animals:

> Verily Allah has prescribed ihsan (proficiency, perfection) in all things. So if you kill then kill well; and if you slaughter, then slaughter well. Let each one of you sharpen his blade and let him spare suffering to the animal he slaughters.” ([Sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/nawawi40/17))

And the Prophet Muhammad is also noted for promoting kindness to animals, including sparing their lives:

> He who takes pity even on a sparrow and spares its life, God will be merciful to him on the Day of Judgement. ([Islam and Animals](http://www.chai.org.il/en/compassion/islam/heritage_islam2_i.htm))
>
> There is a reward for kindness to every living thing ([Sunnah.com reference.](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/126))

### Fatawa

As far as I know, scholars agree that vegetarianism and veganism is fine (provided you're aware that eating meat is halal [with the exclusions in the Qur'an]).  Some examples sourced from [Fatwas on Vegetarianism](http://www.animalsinislam.com/halal-living/fatwas/) (more are found by following the link):

> So traditionally Muslims were semi-vegetarians. The Prophet was, I mean, technically, the Prophet (SAWS) was in that category. He was not a meat-eater. Most of his meals did not have meat in them. And the proof of that is clearly in the Muwatta—when Sayyidina Umar says, ‘Beware of meat, because it has an addiction like the addiction of wine.’  -- [Hamza Yusuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza_Yusuf)
>
> A Muslim may be a vegetarian. However, he should not regard eating meat as prohibited.  -- [Mufti Ebrahim Desai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebrahim_Desai)
>
> Vegetarianism is halal. Meat is not compulsory. Any food is permissible provided it is not harmful. Muslims are free to eat whatever they want provided it is halal.  -- [Sayyid Fadhlullah](http://www.eslam.de/begriffe/f/fadhlullah.htm)

The Salafi [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/2521) say even veganism is okay:

> I'm [vegan], I mean I do not eat... any [thing] that have to do with animal... can I be a Muslim and still [not] eat meat and animal [products]?
>
> Yes, you can be a Muslim without eating these animal products.
>
> ...
>
> You should not think that it is better to abstain from these foods, or that doing so will be rewarded, or that a vegetarian is closer to Allaah than others, and so on.  -- [Sheikh M. S. Al-Munajjid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Al-Munajjid)

Comment: This is the best workaround. I'm not vegetarian myself but couldn't slaughter or kill animals so I'm practically doing the same.

Comment: I went there today, and saw them kill a bunch of sheep.  I'm in China at a Hui mosque, so it looked much like the picture.  It wasn't a great feeling, but it wasn't as bad as I thought it'd be.

Answer (score -3):

Who said the blood is to reach Allah? Who? Our deeds do reach him, but not the blood of an animal.

The animals are not slaughtered for the sake of being slaughtered. They are slaughtered so that it would be given to the hungry, the poor, those in need. NO religion but Islam has such a practice. It shows love! In Islam it is encouraged for Muslims to break bread with the poor so the poor won't be distanced from the rest, the poor would get what need and also the rich won't become arrogant.

As for a Muslim, not its generally not permissible to be vegetarian. Yet for one who wants to convert, I won't push them into following all Islam's commandments at once. Our prophet when he came he incrementally brought the commandments. ~Example: First the verses of Wine having adverse effects was revealed, then verses of not praying when you are drunk and then later verses about it being forbidden.

As for an argument. Ask the vegetarian, how do you eat plants? Don't they have a soul? Aren't they living? Why are you killing them?

Comment: she says animal are not slaughtered for their blood and meat.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the argument is more like: "It's only a made a Tradition, Muslims wrongly think the blood reaches to Allah"

Comment: @cerberus23 kindly read my comment again, I edited my comment.

Comment: I read it, and its ok (no downvotes from me). Her argument is: since No meat nor blood reaches Allah but the Taqwa, then it shouldn't matter to slaughter animals.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Some scholars say if one doesn't eat meat for 40 days then you must read adhan in their ears again. In this world we follow Allah. Allah has given us permission do eat some animals. He said it's Halal. It's of his sustenance. The act of one refraining himself from it is like saying: "oh allah I don't want your Halal". It's similar to that of some Muslims who were suppose to pray half- prayers when they were in battle but still said to the prophet that we want to pray in full. It's like refusing the host's bounty. It's rude. Aside from it being rude. It's against Allah reason.

Comment: There are multiple verses in Quran indicating them as bounty. In addition in Islam has the best way so the animal won't be harmed. And if you wish to change your logic from killing to not having feeling or not enjoying Allah's bounties then it's no problem at all. Enjoy your own way of religion.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones  very correct. One should not eat meat for 40 consecutive days. While one must also have meat once in every 40 days.  I don't know why you seem to not have access to the narration

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones would sharing a reference suffice or you would still have questions? If so please let me know all at once so I can provide a complete answer

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones see [here](http://www.bahlool.se/2013/09/09/shia-hadither-om-kottatande/) *Muhammad b. Ya'qub from 'Ali b. Ibrahim from his father from Ibn Abi `Umayr from Hisham b. Salim from Abu 'Abdillah عليه السلام. He said: Flesh builds flesh, and whoever abandons it for forty days his nature (khuluq) is worsened, and whoever’s nature is worsened then call the adhan in his ear.*

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones also *And from a number of our companions from Ahmad b. Muhammad from Ibn Abi Nasr from al-Husayn b. Khalid. He said: I said to Abu ‘l-Hasan عليه السلام: The people say: Whoever abandons eating meat for three days his nature is worsened. So he said: They have lied, rather (it is that) whoever does not eat meat for forty days his nature and his body are altered, and that it is due to the transfer of the nutfa in the measure of forty days.* The entire page is about this. Please read. Let me know if you have any other questions. I don't know if I forgot or missed your comment.sry

Comment: Thank you!  (I suppose I should also mention that I'm no longer a vegetarian.  Allah says it's okay to eat meat in the Qur'an ([Qur'an 6:118](https://quran.com/6/118)), and I trust Allah.)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones That's the spirit. To apply your critical thinking within the scope of Quran and trusted narrations.

Comment: (I'm doing a comment clean up; I deleted my old comments.  Would it be possible to quote this hadith in the answer?  It's hard to find within the comments.)